# Adjusting SAS scatterplot axis to begin and end in an integer divisble by 5

Tags: sas

```
proc sgplot data= group;
  scatter x=test1 y=test2 / markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled color=black);
  xaxis label='Test 1 Scores'
  min =30
  max =95

  ;
  yaxis label='Test 2 Scores'
  min=35
  max=95
  ;
run;
```

I've been trying to adjust the vales showing on the axis of my scatterplot so that the values are divisible by 5, however despite saying my min and max values are 35 and 95, the min and max values showing are 40 and 100. I attempted to see what would occur if I said the min value was 30, but it still showed as 40. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try the values statement instead. `values=(30 to 95 by 5)`

Comment: Doh, oh my goodness thank you, thats so incredibly simple and obvious. I feel silly now.

Comment: I don't think there's anything to feel silly. SAS overrides the min based on the data, I suspect there's a note in the log that says something to that effect, but it's not what you intuitively expect. I expect if I say minimum it'll do minimum...but it's the defaults and exceptions that catch you ;)